# No desaparece mensaje de validación al corregir en Angular

Tags: angular, formularios, validación, angular10, angular11

Tengo las siguientes funciones en mi .ts de mi componente en angular el cual contienen lo siguiente

Funciona para ver lo que envía el formulario

```javascript
  registerUser(){
    this.formSubmited=true;
    console.log(this.registerForm.value);
    console.log("prueba")
  }
```

Funciona para realizar la validacion obteniendo si el campo es invalido

```javascript
  validationRequired(campo: string):boolean { 
    if ( this.registerForm.get(campo)?.invalid && this.formSubmited) { 
     return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
      
  }
```

Por ultimo tengo mi html mi gIf para mostrar la validacion y la configuración de mi formulario

```html
<form 
[formGroup]="registerForm"
id="registerForm"
role="form" 
class="form-validate"
(ngSubmit)="registerUser()">
    
<p *ngIf="validationRequired('email')" class="col-auto errores">
  <span >Los campos son obligatorios</span>
</p>
```

Mi mensaje de error se muestra al enviar mi formulario por medio de mi botón pero no borra el mensaje al volver a corregir la validación y hacer el envío nuevamente

Answer (score 1):

Tu error se encuentra en los operadores lógicos de tu if

```javascript
this.registerForm.get(campo)?.invalid && this.formSubmited
```

dado que `this.registerForm.get(campo)?.invalid` al corregir el valor va a retornar `false` y for tanto `false && true` es `false`.

> Ten en cuenta que `this.registerForm.get(campo)?.invalid` ahora es `false` por operadores lógicos `false && loquesea` (false o true). Siempre va ser false

Comment: intente cambiando el false y true volteándolos y también usando el operador '!' en vez del '?', pero no logro aun hacer que funcione me podrias dar una idea mas por favor

Comment: Creo que no me hice entender bien lo que pasa es que al corregir `this.registerForm.get(campo)?.invalid` va a retornar siempre `false`. Y según operadores lógicos `false` && `lo que sea` es `false`

Comment: entiendo el punto pero que puedo hacer para solucionarlo intente ahora cambiar y agregar el signo ! en el ngIf y funciona pero al volver querer mostrar la alerta no lo hace

Comment: Ese es el problema no hagas prueba y error, pues te vas a confundir más. Analiza bien tu código, ahora para darte la pista solo separa el `if` 

Comment: Va intentare y te comento el resultado gracias!

Comment: La verdad no logre internarlo amigo no soy muy bueno aun, me podrias dar otra pista por favor

Comment: Ok mira. Como te explico `this.registerForm.get(campo)?.invalid` ahora va a retornar siempre `false` pues ahora si es valido por lo tanto deberías cambiar el valor a `if( !this.registerForm.get(campo)?.invalid && this.formSubmited )`. Con esto estas diciendo **si el campo es valido y se dio submit** en tu función

Comment: Realice esta instrucción de acuerdo a lo que me diste pero no lo logro hacer:( soy algo novato aun si puedes seguirme ayudando te lo agradecería mucho  if ( this.registerForm.get(campo)?.invalid){
  return true;
}else{
if( !this.registerForm.get(campo)?.invalid && this.formSubmited ){
    return true
;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
  }